# Maximizing Likelihood, Julia

Tags: optimization, julia, log-likelihood

I have a log-likelihood function and I want to maximize it in respect to theta (N), and it is defined as:

```
 function loglik(theta,n,r)
    N=theta;k=length(n);
    ar1=float(lgamma(N+1));ar2=sum(n)*log(sum(n)/(k*N));ar3=(k*N-sum(n))*log(1-(sum(n))/(k*N));
    par=float(lgamma((N-r)+1));
    return(-(ar1+ar2+ar3-par)) end
```

The I use Optim.jl's `optimize` function as:

```
   r=optimize(b->loglik(b,nn, 962), 978, BFGS() );
```

Where  nn is an array. And I get this error:

```
   ERROR:MethodError no method matching optimize (::#46#47,::Float64, ::Optim.BFGS)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there! You need to initialize it with an array.

```
optimize(b->loglik(first(b),nn,962), [978.,], BFGS())
```

(though you still need to provide us with `nn` for this answer to show the output)

edit: since b is a scalar in loglik, I changed it to `b->loglik(first(b),nn, 962)` as suggested by Chris Rackauckas below.

Comment: Still doesn't work, nn is an 91-element Array{Int64,1}

Comment: `b->loglik(first(b),nn,962)` or `b->loglik(b[1],nn,962)` since it wants a scalar.

Comment: Great, yeah, I'm so used to `x` being a vector that I hadn't noticed it was a scalar in maxlik. Don't forget to accept an answer when you have a solution that works. Would be great if you could generate an `nn` in your question as well.